# python3 i2c register write problem

Tags: python, i2c, pigpio

I'm writing code to read a `i2c` pressure sensor's data using python3, do the math and print in the screen. The problem is that I need a faster measurement time. I read in the sensor's manual that I can do that simple writing in the sensor's register (0x14) changing some oversampling values, the original code is the following:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
import pigpio

while True:
              
    pi = pigpio.pi()
    h = pi.i2c_open(1, 0x78)
    pi.i2c_write_device(h, [0xAC])
    time.sleep(0.2)
    (b, d) = pi.i2c_read_device(h, 6)
    pi.i2c_close(h)
    pi.stop()

    p1 = bin(d[1])[2:].zfill(8)  #BridgeDat1
    p2 = bin(d[2])[2:].zfill(8)  #BridgeDat2
    p3 = bin(d[3])[2:].zfill(8)  #BridgeDat3
    t1 = bin(d[4])[2:].zfill(8)  #TempDat1
    t2 = bin(d[5])[2:].zfill(8)  #TempDat2
    bpress = p1+p2+p3            #concatenate values in bytes
    dpress = int(bpress, 2)      #convert to Decimal
    ipress = (((((dpress/12305550)*100)*6)/100)-2.2)*1.042 #calibration factor is 1.042
    Pressure = round(ipress, 3)  #round the number to 3 number after dot
    btemp = t1+t2                #concatenate values in bytes
    dtemp = int(btemp, 2)        #convert to Decimal
    itemp = (((dtemp/65536)*190)-40)*0.954 #calibration factor is 0.954
    Temperature = round(itemp,1) #round the number to 3 number after dot
    print(Pressure,Temperature)
```

I tried to do the following to write in this register:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
import pigpio

def data_to_OSRP_OSRT(word):
    return word[0:10], word[11:13], word[14:15] 

def main():

    # Define registers values from datasheet
    oscg = 0x14  # Configuration register
    addr = 0x78  # Address of sensor
    overp = "00110"
    overt = "01"

    bus = pigpio.pi()
    h = bus.i2c_open(1, addr)

    while True:
        if h >= 0:
            a2 = bus.i2c_read_word_data(h,oscg)
            data = bin(a2)
            (oto10,osr_pressure,osr_temperature) = data_to_OSRP_OSRT(data)

            print("binary       =",bin(a2))
            print("begginer     =",oto10)
            print("pressure     =",osr_pressure)
            print("temperature  =",osr_temperature)
            end_osr = oto10 + overp + overt
            print("concatenate  =",end_osr)      
            endint = int(end_osr,base=2)
            endbin = bin(endint)
            print("bconcatenate =",endbin)
            buswrite = bus.i2c_process_call(h,oscg,endint)
            print("writeprocess =",buswrite)
            print("bwriteprocess=",bin(buswrite))
            time.sleep(0.2)
        bus.stop()
        break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But what happened is that when I read the sensor's register after the write process, the value won't change at all.

[image]

[The sensor's manual](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IrOiQ60cEqCrW1DLy6InrHl0aVvNNV1o/view?usp=sharing%5B)

Comment: Please provide a link to the sensor manual or the name of the device

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IrOiQ60cEqCrW1DLy6InrHl0aVvNNV1o/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This seems to be more a question about the sensor itself, and may not be relevant to Raspberry Pi.

Comment: but is the way i'm doing correct ?

Comment: The manual is very difficult to understand, this doesn't look like a proper data sheet from a manufacturer so what you need to supply as the data to register 0x14 I cannot say with any certainty. However, looking at your code I don't think it is correct, I think you will need to delay after the write to the configuration register at address 0x14 before reading the result, you need to give the sensor time to acquire the data, the process_call method doesn't do that.   The original example wrote 10101100 to the device, waited and then read the results.

Comment: I guess, and it is a guess, that you need to write (0x14, 0x18)  to the device (cmd and configuration data) then send 0xAC (I am guessing this starts the conversion process) wait for 29 milliseconds, and finally read the 6 bytes of data, check the first status byte is ok.  then process the data bytes and scale the values.